# Drupal Commerce Kickstart cloud zoom image not working?

Tags: 7, media, commerce

I am using Drupal commerce kickstart. I want to show the thumbnail images. I am using custom html theme in my project. How to show the thumbnail image in product page? Please anyone guide to me.I am new to Drupal commerce kickstart.[image: I want to display the product page like this image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the following modules (since it basically creates this straight out of the box). Once you customize it you can define how you want hte widgets to appear and essentially create the view as you have outlined above.

- [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)
- [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)